# How to scroll to the center of the div in react using javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, scrolltop, scrollto

How to scroll to the center of the div element using plain javascript? My requirement is to scroll to center of div after rerender of a component. I tried using "useEffect" and "useLayoutEffect" but both triggers before the DOM is painted and not after it.

```
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {

    document.getElementsByClassName('ms-DetailsList-contentWrapper')[0].scrollTo(0, document.getElementsByClassName('ms-DetailsList-contentWrapper')[0].scrollHeight / 2);

  })

React.useEffect(() => {

    document.getElementsByClassName('ms-DetailsList-contentWrapper')[0].scrollTo(0, document.getElementsByClassName('ms-DetailsList-contentWrapper')[0].scrollHeight / 2);

  })
```

Note this works fine if I do it from console window after DOM is loaded?
How to make this work in react?

Comment: Should work. What does `element` evaluate to?
Also, where does that type come from—is this TypeScript?

Comment: Yes, This is typescript. "element" evaluates to type "Element"

Comment: Why did you edit the question that way? The code is repetitive now and I don't see what benefit you get from wrapping it in those React fn calls.

Comment: Also, I wasn't asking what type `element` evaluates to, but what its actual *value* is—can you paste the output from printing `element` please.